# How to do pattern replacement with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match 'windowsXP' in this string:

```
windowsXP|7|8
```

Or

```
windowsXP 7 8
```

I wrote a pattern to match it:

```
 ([^0-9|])+[0-9\.]+.*
```

Why doesn't it match? It's the | making the trouble in the bracket. I tried escaping it but it didn't work either.

```
([^0-9\|])+[0-9\.]+.*
```

Comment: What is the pattern? `word|number|number`? Something else?

Comment: word|number|number, but the '|' could be optional.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t3dskG/1

Comment: With optional pipes: https://regex101.com/r/iKQjGe/1

Comment: @PM77-1 my actual case is that the character is not ascii characters, so \w won't match.. Sorry for confustion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look:

1. `([^0-9|])+` find characters different from digits and pipes
2. `[0-9\.]+` attempts matching a digit or a period, but there is a pipe that the expression cannot catch.

Use

```
^([^|\s]+)[|\s](\d+)[|\s](\d+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/qR09dy/5)

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^|\s]+                  any character except: '|', whitespace (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [|\s]                    any character of: '|', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [|\s]                    any character of: '|', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolasoNT21QsFWoUgpTiM6riamOFZbMxpEacSkILOUuEpSi0vii0uKgIqVyjPzUvLLiyMCasxrLJS4Cooy80o0ilL10oDiiTk5GmBTdRRgWjQ1uf7/BwA)**:

```py
import re
regex = r"^([^|\s]+)[|\s](\d+)[|\s](\d+)"
test_str = "windowsXP|7|8"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

**Results**: `[('windowsXP', '7', '8')]`

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to math both cases:

```sh
^[^|\s]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXZdl1/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^|\s]+`: Match 1+ of any character that are not `|` and not whitespace

Answer (score -1):

It is rather simple. Just think of selecting the alphabets not negating numerics.

```js
regex = \[a-z]*\i
```